# Adding child nodes to a treeview in C#

Tags: c#, treeview

I have a treeview that contains Car Makes and their respective Models.  I have a button that adds a new Make (parent Node).

```
private void btnMake_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string inputMake;
    inputMake = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter Make: ", "Add Car Manufacturer");
    carMake.Add(inputMake); // arrayList to store car Makes
    carTree.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(inputMake));
}
```

What I am having problems with is adding Model (child nodes).  I have a button to add model and I don't know how to differentiate the appropriate parent node.

I currently have the following code:

```
private void btnModel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string inputModel;
    int index = carTree.Nodes.IndexOf(carTree.SelectedNode);
    //MessageBox.Show(carMake[index].ToString());
    //inputModel = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("asfdasdf", "asdfasdf");
    //carTree.Nodes[index].Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(inputModel));
}
```

The last lines are commented out due to testing . . . I am putting the care Makes (parent nodes) into an ArrayList but am having issues accessing the arraylist.  This line returns an error:

```
 //MessageBox.Show(carMake[index].ToString());
```

Ultimately I would like some help with the most efficient way to add child nodes to a respective parent node.

Comment: How does it work ? Will it add child nodes to the currently highlighted node ? Where and how is the parent node choosen ?

Comment: its a windows form app.  so the parent node would be chosen by selecting and then clicking the add child button.  i also have to figure out an exception message if no parent node has been selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
if(carTree.SelectedNode == null)
  MessageBox.Show("Please select a node first");    

carTree.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("Child"));
```

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to mark this question as answered if your problem is solved.